# Not entering into click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

The control is not passing into click event so can anyone please suggest whats wrong with the code below and any tutorial on this wil be of great help.

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#submit").click(function(event)
{
    alert("hi");
    $.ajax({
   type    : "POST",
   url     : "https://xxxxx/xxx.php",
   data    : {"email": "jason.charity@icloud.com", "password": "people4455!",       "application":"rex"},
   success : function(response) {
     data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
     console.log(data);
     }
  });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wait the page to load before binding the button: `$(function(){ $('#submit).click(...) });`

Comment: @MarcoCI: If you control where the script tag goes, there's almost never a reason to use `ready`.

Comment: @ user: FYI, I've added a couple of side notes to my answer which may be useful.

Answer (score 4):

Two issues:

1. You're missing `});` from the end of your code, so it has a syntax error. (I didn't realize that until I went to run your code through http://jsbeautifier.org/ so I wasn't posting a mess below. Which shows the value of making sure you use reasonable, consistent code formatting!)
2. (If you fix that.) When you do your `$("#submit")`, the element doesn't exist yet, and so that doesn't match any elements. Just move the script block *below* the element in the HTML (this is [generally the recommendation](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom), put your `script` just before the closing `</body>` tag).

Fixing both:

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="myForm">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#submit").click(function (event) {
        alert("hi");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://xxxxx/xxx.php",
            data: {
                "email": "jason.charity@icloud.com",
                "password": "people4455!",
                "application": "rex"
            },
            success: function (response) {
                data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }); // <== This was the missing bit
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Side notes:

1. If your server responds with the correct content type, you don't need `parseJSON` in your `success` handler; jQuery will automatically parse the JSON if the server says that's what it is.
2. Using a doctype is a really, really, really, really good idea. Put `<!doctype html>` at the top of the document.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your function within document.ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//your code here
});
```

Or,

```
$(function(){
//your code here
});
```

And also you are missing `});` at last line of code which would throw an error as mentioned by @T.J. Crowder

Answer (score 0):

you can also use recommended approach, i.e. event delegation on document

```
$(document).on("click","#submit",function(event)
{
    alert("hi");
    $.ajax({
   type    : "POST",
   url     : "https://xxxxx/xxx.php",
   data    : {"email": "jason.charity@icloud.com", "password": "people4455!",       "application":"rex"},
   success : function(response) {
     data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
     console.log(data);
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: $.ajax({
       type    : "POST",
       url     : "https://xxxxxxx/xxx.php",
       data    : {"email": "jason.charity@icloud.com", "password": "people4455!", "application":"rex"},
       success : function(response) {
         data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
         console.log(data);
         }   //now dis console is not working so any suggestion

Comment: do you get success on ajax ?

Answer (score 0):

Put your click into

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(event)
  {
    alert("hi");
    $.ajax({
    type    : "POST",
    url     : "https://xxxxx/xxx.php",
    data    : {"email": "jason.charity@icloud.com", "password": "people4455!",                           "application":"rex"},
    success : function(response) {
    data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
  console.log(data);
   }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#submit").click(function(event){
     alert("hi");
     $.ajax({
       type    : "POST",
       url     : "https://xxxxx/xxx.php",
       data    : {"email": "jason.charity@icloud.com", 
       "password":      "people4455!",       "application":"rex"},
       success : function(response) {
         data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
         console.log(data);
       }
     });
   });
 });
</script>
```

you missed closing "});", Try this script.

Comment: These answers was given in the mean time, I was writing my answer. So couldn't see the answer is already given !!!